# Mapping Observable<Something> to Observable<Void>

Tags: rx-java

I want to perform `task 1` and then `task 2` with no need to combine their emitted items. I have this:

```
interface Service {
    Observable<Something> doTask1();
    Observable<SomethingElse> doTask2();
}
```

Is it a good approach to make them return `Observable<Void>` in order to merge them?
Both tasks are independents, so the first may be return an empty `Observable` but the second one has to be executed anyway.

```
public Observable<Void> doTasks() {
    Observable.merge(service.doTask1(), service.doTask2());
}
```

If so, is there any "correct" way to map an `Observable<Something>` to `Observable<Void>`? I'm doing it like this:

```
public class TaskService implements Service {
    public Observable<Void> doTask1() {
        return getSomething().map(new Func1<Something, Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public Void call(Something something) {
                        return null;
                    }
                });
    } 
}
```

Any advise will be appreciated.

Comment: are you doing something with the emissions of the merged Observable?
what do you do further down the stream with the merged Observable?

Comment: No, I'm not. I just want to perform the task. Emitted items are not importante.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mapping values to Void is a valid way, but, RxJava introduced `Completable`, which is a variant of `Observable` that do not emit items, but just completion and error notification.
You can use it here,as you don't care about the emitted values, then you'll get cleaner API, and also wouldn't need to map the values to mean less ones.

```
public Completable doTasks() {    
    Completable.merge(service.doTask1().toCompletable(), service.doTask2().toCompletable());
}
```